# How do I re-attach a trim panel that has partially popped off?

Tags: pontiac, door

I have a Pontiac Vibe, and the top clip of the rear door panel (that goes around the wheel well) has become unattached.   This panel serves as trim for the door.

I am not sure how to go about getting it on without breaking it.  Do I need to remove the entire panel?  What tools would a mechanic use to attach it?  As of right now, I'm just driving around with it hanging off.  It doesn't really look like it's loose unless you take a close look, since the panel is still attached in all other areas of the door.

Answer (score 1):

These parts are very rigid, which makes them delicate. You have to know where the clips are, and for most cars a putty knife or some kind of wedge will work. Once the clips are popped, you replaced any broken one, and reinstall. I can't speculate on the location of the clips for your particular vehicle, but you can usually tell by feeling around the part. Be careful, as your car could also screws or other stronger parts attaching it to the body.

Comment: I got my mechanic to do it.  so I sitll don't really know how to do it myself.  He actually just glued it, as the clip way broken!